# Can't find PerRequestLifetimeManager class in Unity.MVC4 or Unity(3.0)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, unity-container

I am trying to locate PerRequestLifetimeManager. In MSDN, [it says that it is part of the Unity  3 assembly.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.unity.perrequestlifetimemanager%28v=pandp.30%29.aspx)

I've installed Unity.Mvc4 via Nuget. The package.config says I am using Unity 3.0:

[image]

The **Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll** says I am using Unity 3.0

[image]

I looked inside the DLL using object browser, and the **PerRequestLifetimeManager** is no where to be found.

Am I missing something here?

If someone will suggest an alternative class, I am planning to use a custom PerRequestLifetimeManager found [here](http://www.wiktorzychla.com/2013/03/unity-and-http-per-request-lifetime.html) (if I am unable to find the class).

**EDIT:**

I've uninstalled Unity.Mvc4 and directly installed the Unity3.0 in the package console, here is what I got:

```
PM> Install-Package Unity -version 3.0.1304.1
'Unity 3.0.1304.1' already installed.
Successfully added 'Unity 3.0.1304.1' to RedLions.Presentation.Web.
```

I still can't find the PerRequestLifetimeManager class, even in the official library.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It seems not good to answer my own question when I just instead did it on my own. I can no longer delete my question.

Anyway, here was my solution.

I went straight to the source code of Unity, I found out that the class **does exist** in the same namespace but not in the same assembly. PerRequestLifetimeManager is in **Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Mvc**

[image]

I checked MSDN and it *did* say that its in a different DLL, which I failed to notice. Sorry about that.

It is not part of the Unity package in nuget, but in a different package in Nuget (Unity.Mvc), so here it is: http://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity.Mvc/

I decided to dump Unity.Mvc4 as it is no longer needed, everything is already in the Unity.Mvc. (App_Start/UnityConfig.cs)

Answer (score 1):

you can delete the original DLLS and Uninstall the reinstall.

Comment: Hello, I tried that too. I removed UnityMvc4 and installed just Unity3.0. Still can't find it (see my edited post)

Answer (score 1):

Run the following from PCM, Package Manager Console:

```
Install-Package Unity.Mvc
```

This will give you the DLL `Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Mvc` where it is.